# Non-Central One-Sided Correlation Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

Assume I have a pair of vectors $a,b$. Upon discussing their correlation $\rho_{a,b}$ we can usually test whether $\rho_{a,b}=0$, $\rho_{a,b}>0$ or $\rho_{a,b}<0$ (as asked previously [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225874/one-sided-hypothesis-test-for-correlation) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148203/one-sided-significance-test-for-correlation)). These tests can be easily conducted in R using `cor.test`. For Pearson's $\rho$ we even have a specified distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis on independence:

$$t=\rho\sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-\rho^2}}\sim t_{n-2}$$

Now, assume I would like to test for a strong positive correlation. That is, my null hypothesis would be $H_0:\rho_{a,b}\ge 0.7$. What would be the distribution of the test statistic? Is there a way to conduct this using `cor.test`?

Comment: Unless $n$ is very small, [Fisher's Transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Fisher%20transform*%20correl*&searchOn=3) is usually applied along with a Normal approximation.  Your question is asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436903, but it's not terribly informative!